# Win32 (C) application freezes after some GetWindowText?

Tags: c, winapi, clion, win32gui

I'm building a Sudoku Win32 Application in C. I have some issues with GetWindowText(), I guess, that works correctly for an undefined number of times but then the application freezes, without hanging (the state of the process is normal, no "app.exe stopped working"), no more values can be inserted in Edit Boxes, Menus are unclickable, only the minimize and close buttons respond.  I've already inserted some MessageBoxes but it all seems to work fine until the issue comes unexpectedly. I've already tried to debug with multiple debuggers, the CLion (the IDE I'm using), the Codeblocks one, and even the Windows integrated one (Visual Studio) but nothing relevant came up. I'm freaking out. Please help me, and ask me for more details if necessary, but I think that's all. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <scrnsave.h>

#define N 9
#define SRN 3
#define K 64 //Celle nascoste all'inizio
#define ID_STUFF_GO 9000
#define ID_MODE_NOHINT 4200
#define ID_MODE_HINT 4201

typedef struct{
    int correctVal;
    int insertedVal;
    bool visible;
}cell;

cell puzzle[N][N];
HWND grid[N][N];
bool hint=true;
bool ready=false;
int count=0;

int CDECL MessageBoxPrintf(unsigned int , const char *, const char *, ...);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void sudokuInit(void);
void diagonalInit(void);
void boxInit(int, int);
bool fillMissing(int, int);
bool notInBox(int, int, int);
bool notInRow(int, int);
bool notInColumn(int, int);
bool isLegalValue(int, int, int);
void setVisibleValues(void);
void createFile(void);
bool checkValue(int, int);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){

    static char appName[]= TEXT("Sudoku");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;

    //------------------- Definizione finestra -------------------//
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; //Definizione stili della finestra, in questo caso il contenuto viene centrato sia verticalmente che orizontalmente all'interno della finestra
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc; //Collega la procedura che gestira i messaggi provenienti dalla finestra
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0; //Spazio extra per specifici scopi del programma
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0; //Spazio extra per specifici scopi del programma
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance; //Imposta l'istanza che gestisce la finestra
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); //Carica l'icona del programma
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW); //Carica il cursore del mouse da usare nel programma
    wndclass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(63,81,181)); //Recupera un oggetto grafico, in questo caso un pennelo che colora lo sfondo
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = appName; //Configura il menu della finestra
    wndclass.lpszClassName = appName; //Definisce il nome della classe della finestra
    //------------------------------------------------------------//

    if(!RegisterClass (&wndclass)){
        MessageBoxPrintf(MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR,appName,"Questo programma richiede Windows NT!");
        return 0;
    }

    //------------------ Creazione finestra ----------------------//
    hwnd = CreateWindow (appName,            //nome della classe della finestra
                        TEXT("Sudoku Game"), //Titolo della finestra
                        WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_MINIMIZEBOX|WS_SYSMENU, //Stile della finestra
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,       //Posizione orizontale iniziale
                        CW_USEDEFAULT,       //Posizione verticale iniziale
                        525,                 //Larghezza iniziale
                        565,                 //ALtezza iniziale
                        NULL,                //Gestore della finestra madre
                        NULL,                //Gestore del menu della finestra
                        hInstance,           //Gestore dell'istanza del programma
                        NULL);               //Parametri di creazione
    //------------------------------------------------------------//

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow); //Mostra la finestra sullo schermo
    sudokuInit();
    UpdateWindow(hwnd); //Ordina alla finestra di riempire(dipingere) se stessa

    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){ //Recupera i messaggi dalla coda dei messaggi
        /*if(count==K){
            MessageBoxPrintf(MB_ICONINFORMATION,appName,"Gioco terminato!");
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_DESTROY, MAKEWPARAM(FALSE, 0), MAKELPARAM(FALSE,0));
        }*/
        TranslateMessage(&msg); //Traduce gli eventi di input (tastiera/mouse) in messaggi
        DispatchMessage(&msg); //Invia i messaggi alla procedura della finestra
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

int CDECL MessageBoxPrintf(unsigned int type, const char *title, const char *content, ...){
    char buffer[1024];
    va_list pArgList;

    va_start(pArgList, content);
    _vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer)/ sizeof(char), content, pArgList);
    va_end(pArgList);

    return MessageBox(NULL, buffer, title, type);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect;
    HFONT hfont = CreateFont(50,0,0,0,FW_SEMIBOLD,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"Century Gothic");
    HMENU hSubMenu, hMenu;
    int i, j, k=10, m=10, n, id;
    char out[2];

    switch(message){
        case WM_CREATE:
            hMenu = CreateMenu();

            hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
            AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_MODE_NOHINT, "Senza suggerimenti");
            AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_MODE_HINT, "Con suggerimenti");
            AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, "Modalita'");
            ModifyMenu(hMenu, ID_MODE_HINT, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_CHECKED, ID_MODE_HINT, "Con suggerimenti");

            hSubMenu = CreatePopupMenu();
            AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, ID_STUFF_GO, "Nope");
            AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hSubMenu, "Difficolta'");

            SetMenu(hwnd, hMenu);

            for (i=0; i<N ; i++){
                for (j=0; j<N; j++) {
                    id=i*10+j+1;

                    grid[i][j]= CreateWindow("EDIT",
                                 "",
                                 ES_CENTER | ES_NUMBER | WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                                 k, m, 50, 50,
                                 hwnd, (HMENU)id, NULL, NULL);

                    SendMessage(grid[i][j], WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfont, MAKELPARAM(FALSE, 0));

                    if((j+1)%3==0)
                        k+=60;
                    else
                        k+=55;
                }
                k=10;

                if((i+1)%3==0)
                    m+=60;
                else
                    m+=55;
            }

            return 0;

        case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
            hdc = (HDC) wParam;

            return SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(63,81,181));

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam)){
                case ID_MODE_HINT:
                    hint=true;
                    ModifyMenu(hMenu, ID_MODE_HINT, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_CHECKED, ID_MODE_HINT, "Con suggerimenti");
                    ModifyMenu(hMenu, ID_MODE_NOHINT, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_UNCHECKED, ID_MODE_NOHINT, "Senza suggerimenti");
                    break;
                case ID_MODE_NOHINT:
                    hint=false;
                    ModifyMenu(hMenu, ID_MODE_HINT, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_UNCHECKED, ID_MODE_HINT, "Con suggerimenti");
                    ModifyMenu(hMenu, ID_MODE_NOHINT, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_CHECKED, ID_MODE_NOHINT, "Senza suggerimenti");
                    break;
                case ID_STUFF_GO:
                    MessageBoxPrintf(MB_ICONINFORMATION,"Test", "NOPE!");
                    break;
            }
            switch(HIWORD(wParam)){
                case EN_CHANGE:
                    if(ready){
                        MessageBoxPrintf(MB_ICONEXCLAMATION,"Test", "Acquiring");
                        GetWindowText((HWND)lParam, out, 2);
                        UINT err= GetLastError();
                        n=atoi(out);
                        id=(int)GetMenu((HWND)lParam);
                        MessageBoxPrintf(MB_ICONEXCLAMATION,"Test", "Ready");
                        if(checkValue(n,id)){
                            if(hint)
                                MessageBoxPrintf(MB_ICONINFORMATION,"Test", "Giusto");
                                //SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(76,175,80));
                            count++;
                        }else
                            if(hint)
                                MessageBoxPrintf(MB_ICONSTOP,"Test", "Sbagliato");
                                //SetTextColor(hdc,RGB(244,67,54));
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return 0;

        case WM_PAINT:
            BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps); //Inizia a riempire(dipingere) la finestra

            GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect); //Ottiene le dimensioni sullo schermo della finestra

            for (i=0; i<N; i++){
                for (j=0; j<N; j++){
                    if(puzzle[i][j].visible){
                        itoa(puzzle[i][j].correctVal, out,10);

                        Edit_SetText(grid[i][j], out);

                        SendMessage(grid[i][j],EM_SETREADONLY,(WPARAM)TRUE, MAKELPARAM(FALSE, 0));

                    }
                    SetTextColor(GetDC(hwnd), RGB(63,81,181));
                }
            }

            ready=true;

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps); //Finisce di riempire(dipingere) la finestra
            return 0;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0); //Inserisce un messaggio di uscita alla coda dei messaggi
            return 0;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam); //Esegue il processo predefinito per i messaggi
    }
}

void sudokuInit(void){
    srand(time(NULL));

    diagonalInit();

    fillMissing(0, SRN);

    setVisibleValues();

    createFile();
}

void diagonalInit(void){
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<N; i+=SRN)
        boxInit(i, i);
}

void boxInit(int r, int c){
    int i, j, num;

    for (i=0; i<SRN; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<SRN; j++) {
            do{
                num=rand()%N+1;
            }while(!notInBox(r, c, num));

            puzzle[r+i][c+j].correctVal=num;
            puzzle[r+i][c+j].visible=true;
        }
    }
}

bool fillMissing(int i, int j){
    int num;

    if (j>=N && i<N-1){
        i++;
        j=0;
    }
    if (i>=N && j>=N)
        return true;

    if (i<SRN){
        if (j<SRN)
            j=SRN;
    }
    else if (i<N-SRN){
        if (j==(i/SRN)*SRN)
            j+=SRN;
    }
    else{
        if (j==N-SRN){
            i++;
            j=0;
            if (i>=N)
                return true;
        }
    }

    for (num=1; num<=N; num++){
        if (isLegalValue(i, j, num)){
            puzzle[i][j].correctVal=num;
            puzzle[i][j].visible=true;

            if (fillMissing(i, j+1))
                return true;

            puzzle[i][j].correctVal=0;
            puzzle[i][j].visible=true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool isLegalValue(int i, int j, int num){
    return notInRow(i, num) && notInColumn(j, num) && notInBox(i-i%SRN, j-j%SRN, num);
}

bool notInRow(int i, int num){
    int j;

    for (j=0; j<N; j++)
        if (puzzle[i][j].correctVal==num)
            return false;

    return true;
}

bool notInColumn(int j, int num){
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        if (puzzle[i][j].correctVal==num)
            return false;

    return true;
}

bool notInBox(int rS, int cS, int num){
    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<SRN; i++)
        for (j=0; j<SRN; j++)
            if (puzzle[rS+i][cS+j].correctVal==num)
                return false;

    return true;
}

void setVisibleValues(void){
    int i, j, cellId, count=K;

    while(count!=0){
        cellId=rand()%(N*N)+1;

        i=cellId/N;
        j=cellId%N;
        j=j-1;

        if(puzzle[i][j].visible){
            count--;
            puzzle[i][j].visible=false;
        }
    }

}

void createFile(void){
    FILE *file;
    char fileName[MAX_PATH], prefix[]="sudoku";
    time_t id = time(NULL);
    int i, j;

    sprintf(fileName, "%s-%ld.txt", prefix, id);

    file=fopen(fileName,"w");

    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
        for (j=0; j<N; j++){
            if(i!=0 || j!=0)
                fprintf(file,",");
            fprintf(file,"%d", puzzle[i][j].correctVal);
        }


    fclose(file);
}

bool checkValue(int n, int cell){
    MessageBoxPrintf(MB_APPLMODAL,"Checking value", "Hey there!");
    int i=0, j=0, op=0;
    op=(int)cell/10;

    switch(op){
        case 0:
            i=0;
            break;
        case 1:
            i=1;
            break;
        case 2:
            i=2;
            break;
        case 3:
            i=3;
            break;
        case 4:
            i=4;
            break;
        case 5:
            i=5;
            break;
        case 6:
            i=6;
            break;
        case 7:
            i=7;
            break;
        case 8:
            i=8;
            break;
        default:
            MessageBoxPrintf(MB_ICONERROR, "Errore", "Impossibile determinare la riga");
            break;
    }

    op=(int)(cell-1)%10;

    switch(op){
        case 0:
            j=0;
            break;
        case 1:
            j=1;
            break;
        case 2:
            j=2;
            break;
        case 3:
            j=3;
            break;
        case 4:
            j=4;
            break;
        case 5:
            j=5;
            break;
        case 6:
            j=6;
            break;
        case 7:
            j=7;
            break;
        case 8:
            j=8;
            break;
        default:
            MessageBoxPrintf(MB_ICONERROR, "Errore", "Impossibile determinare la colonna");
            break;
    }

    puzzle[i][j].insertedVal=n;

    MessageBoxPrintf(MB_APPLMODAL,"Checking value", "Detected!");

    if(puzzle[i][j].insertedVal == puzzle[i][j].correctVal)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

This is what it looks like when started:
[image]

Comment: "*without hanging (the state of the process is normal*" which load does the machine show? An endless-loop somewhere?

Comment: @alk No load, the process stop using the CPU (0%).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program eats all available resources. This line gets new `DC` but never releases it to the system.

```
SetTextColor(GetDC(hwnd), RGB(63,81,181));
```

You should delete this line. Setting color and immediately forgetting HDC does not make any sense.

I would also think about moving code witch reads or modifies edit controls form `WM_PAINT` to better place. `WM_PAINT` should only paint main window contents. In your case (background is painted ny class brush) it could be left out altogether.

Comment: So, how should I set the colour for all the writable edit windows?

Comment: `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` shoud return handle to brush. Read-only or disabled edit controls do not send the `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` message; instead, they send the `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` message. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-ctlcoloredit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-ctlcoloredit) Remember to create brush once and reuse it.

Comment: Removing the WM_CTLCOLOREDIT helps partially, I managed to fill all the edit boxes apart from one.

Comment: And where I should fill the edit boxes that need to be pre-filled if not in WM_PAINT?

Comment: If you need to do it once - `WM_CREATE` - after controls creation.

Comment: Hmm. If I fill them in WM_CREATE, nothing shows up. Only blank edit controls.

Comment: Because `SudokuInit` is called after window creation and when handling `WM_CREATE` you do not have properly initialized data. So fill edit controls after `SudokuInit` call.

Comment: My bad, sorry. :|

Comment: Now, I managed to fill all the cells, but I need some help with the colour thing. I'm a little newbie, this is my first time using Win32. I'm following the Windows API 5th Edition by Charles Petdoz.

Comment: Create brush and store it in global variable `EditBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255,255,192));`. Handle `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` and `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` returning this brush. You may also need to `SetBkColor( hdc, RGB(...) );` before return.

Comment: I get error "initializer element is not constant" from this HBRUSH EditBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(63,81,181)); declared as a gloabal variable

Comment: `EditBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(63,81,181));` put in `WinMain`, `HBRUSH EditBrush;` in global scope.

Comment: I've done that now, but the text colour is not changing it's still black. I would like to set it like before, indigo(editable) controls, black (read-only) controls.

Comment: `SetTextColor( hdc, RGB(...) );` in `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` before return.

Comment: Thanks, now it works! But is it possible to change the text colour after creation? (i.e red wrong value, green correct)?

Comment: Probably I'm annoying you so much, I'm sorry.

Comment: When handling `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` get control id (`int control_id = GetDlgCtrlID( (HWND) lParam );`) and set color and brush depending on this id. From your `WM_CREATE` it look that id could be translated to array indexes.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Daniel_Sęk ! And sorry for begging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179737/discussion-between-mattgeek-and-daniel-sek).